# Populating initialState in reducer through localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react/redux app where I need to populate a prop from state initially with localStorage.

I was thinking of doing it with something like this

```
const initialState = (() => {
  let username = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
  if (!username) {
    username = '';
  }
  return {
    username: username
  };
})();
```

I heard that it's not really a good practice to complicate the initialState with logic, but I haven't found any other ways of doing it

Is there a cleaner workaround?

Comment: This appears to be a perfectly acceptable use case for the lazy load initializer function. I'm not sure why it would be considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use default function parameters to define the initial state in the reducer itself like this with simply an *or* operator. The initial state for user will be first checked in the local storage and if it's *null* then it'll be an empty string.

```
const userReducer = ( state = window.localStorage.getItem("username") || "", action ) => {
  /*
   * some logic to handle actions
   *
   */
  return state;
};
```

Hope this helps !